# Django Models Abstract Base Class - can they be extended across apps?

Tags: python, django, abstract-class

Sorry for the silly question, I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

In almost all of the models in all of the apps in my Django project, there are two common fields - last_updated and date_created. I want to cut down on code by putting them into an abstract base class, of which all of my models extend.

Is there some way to use a single Abstract Base Class across all of my apps - and if so, is there a natural place for that class to live?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an abstract base class is not a registered model, it makes absolutely no difference where it lives. It can be in any Python file that can be imported by the models.py files in each app.

Comment: Thanks very much, Daniel. I've seen your work in the Django community and was wondering when you'd eventually come to my rescue. Appreciated.